# Show Hidden Datasets in ssrs 2008

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am trying to show all hidden datasets created in SSRS report. I don't see the option "Show Hidden dataset" when I right click the Datasets folder. I tried the microsoft link too. How to show all hidden datasets please.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627463(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem in SSRS 2005. One way would be manually remove the datasets in the underlying XML, though I didn't tired yet. But I did solve some other issues by manually modifying the XML.